# How can I run webdev with dart?

Tags: angular, backend, angular-dart, dart-pub, dart-html

How can ı dartlang patch for web
dartlang running but webdev dart didnt work

```
> stagehand web-simple
> pub get
> webdev serve
```

commands didn't work

error message

> C:\Users\SAMSUNG-PC>webdev serve 'webdev' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: have you activate webdev? `pub global activate webdev`